# Binary Tree recursive traversal given min and max

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, traversal

Question (Must be recursive):
Write a function that takes the root of a binary tree, and a min and max value, and finds all the nodes in the tree that fall in between those values, with the LEAST possible visits to other nodes

```
public boolean inRange(Node node, int max, int min)
{
    return root.element() < max && root.elemnt() > min;
}
public void inRangeFinder(Node root, int max, int min)
{
    if (root == null) return; //break
    if(inRange(root, max, min))
        visit(root); //mark as found
    finder(root.leftChild());
    finder(root.rightChild());
}
```

My questions, is the first if statement necessary? And will it cause issues in my left and right subtree traversals?  And most importantly is this the method with the least possible visits?

Comment: Of course it's necessary. How else will you handle the leafs? Didn't you try out your code with some test cases before asking?

Answer (score 0):

Update: sorry, failed to know your program is written in java. I am not a java user, so maybe the answer is not right. Pardon me for that.

> Yes, the first if statement is necessary. If you dismiss the if
>   statement, your program will meet some runtime error for visiting a
>   NULL pointer.
>
> This is basically a left-hand-side first dfs search, so it visits
>   every node only a time. If your tree is not organized, this method
>   costs the least possible visits. But if the tree is **organized tree**,
>   you have to redefine your method to adapt to the specific tree type to
>   gain the least visits.
>
> In order to be recursive, you should define your function name
>   consistently.
>
> ```
> public void finder(Node root, int max, int min)
>           //^^^^^ be the same with your recursive call
> {
>     if (root == null) return; //break
>     if(inRange(root, max, min))
>         visit(root); //mark as found
>     finder(root.leftChild(),max,min);
>                           //^^same arguments
>     finder(root.rightChild(),max,min);
>                           //^^
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a tree which is organized in simple way than you don't have to make an if statement.

It really depends on you tree implementation.

Pseudocode for inorder tree

```
-find value with min key.
-travers in order 
    - and check if result of 
      in order traversal result meets max condition
```

In my opionion you don't even have to check a specific range.

example

```
                 5
              4      8     
            2       6    9    
              3
```

in order means traverse every node just using left time leafs

So to find a specfic seuence between range. Implement an Inorder find 
than execute it for the min value. And the execute it as long your implementation
finds an inorder value for max.

But try to save the results of this process to get the sequence you want to have.

Hope it could help a little bit